# What is the justification that I have to say to show that $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ is not a function?

Tags: functions

What is the justification that I have to say to show that $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ is not a function? after some substitutions I got $y^2 = -1$ at $x = 0$ and $y=0$ at $x =1$, but what are the right verbal words that I should say to convince a student by this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's standard for $x$ to represent input, and $y$ to represent output. So if you input, say,  the number $2$, then you have $$4 - y^2 =1$$ which leads to $$y^2=3$$ and there is no unique value for the output. $y$ might be $\sqrt{3}$, or it might be $-\sqrt{3}$. So there is no automatic way to determine an output given one input.

---

Your observation about the input $0$ is not helpful for determining that this equation doesn't provide a function. When you find $$y^2=-1$$ you can see that there are no real values of $y$ satisfying that. But this just means that *if* the equation makes for a function, then $0$ is not in that function's domain.

Answer (score 1):

To show it's not a function of $x$, find two points on the curve with the same $x$ coordinate. Similarly for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

A function from $X$ to $Y$ can be seen as a relation between $X$ and $Y$ that is *functional* or *right-unique*, meaning that for every $x \in X$ there is at most one $y \in Y$ that stands in the relation to $x$.

Well, if you pick $x = \sqrt{2}$, then both $y=1$ and $y=-1$ stand in the reation to $x$, so it is not right-unique, and thus $y$ is not a function of $x$

Likewisese, if you pick $y=0$ then both $x=1$ and $x=-1$ stand in the relation to $y$, so $x$ is also not a function of $y$

Answer (score 1):

Look at your definition of a function.  It needs some number of inputs and to produce an output.  It is not clear from $x^2-y^2=1$ what is the input and what is the output, so it fails on that criterion.  This indicates that $y=x^2$ would fail even though it passes the vertical line test.  If we assume that $y$ is supposed to be a function of $x$, we just need to find a value of $x$ that works with two values of $y$.  Since $y$ is squared it is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is that you suppose that it is a function and write $y=f(x)$, that is, you suppose that there is functional relation between $y$ and $x$. Then you have, trivially $(f(x))^2=x^2-1$, from which it folows that you *can* have $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and you *can* have $f(x)=-\sqrt{x^2-1}$, so you see that it cannot be a function because it assigns to one $x$ two different $f(x)$´s.